# Codename One: error with MediaManager and URI; can't load libjcef.dylib

Tags: java, codenameone, media-player

I am trying to get audio into my program using URI's and MediaManager, specifically with this method
`Media media = MediaManager.createMedia(uri, false)`. It does not work as I keep getting this error (i've tried setting the boolean in the constructor to both true and false)

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load /Users/mrducky/.m2/repository/com/codenameone/codenameone-cef/84.4.1-M3/codenameone-cef-84.4.1-M3-mac.zip-extracted/cef/macos64/libjcef.dylib
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:827)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1871)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap$1.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:24)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.cef.CefApp.startup(CefApp.java:536)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:212)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$CodenameOneMediaPlayer.init(JavaCEFSEPort.java:256)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$CodenameOneMediaPlayer.<init>(JavaCEFSEPort.java:235)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createMediaAsync(JavaCEFSEPort.java:683)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.createMedia(JavaSEPort.java:9483)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.createMedia(Display.java:3656)
    at com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:255)
    at com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:212)
    at com.example.audio.AudioPlayer.playAudio(AudioPlayer.java:11)
    at com.example.myapp.Game.<init>(Game.java:35)
    at com.example.myapp.Game.getGame(Game.java:40)
    at com.example.myapp.MyApp.init(MyApp.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$3$2.run(Executor.java:334)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.executeSerialCall(Display.java:1395)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1379)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1166)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

I tried deleting the /cef/macos64/... folder and reloading but it did not work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running on an ARM mac? If so we're working on a fix for this but there's a problem related to that. Try using an x86 JVM as a workaround.